# Display integer number as integer and float number as float

Tags: php

I have to display number in php. I take data type in database is **float** . My problem is when the number is not integer it will work fine for example if the number is 4.22 then its fine. But if the number is 4 it display 4.00. but i want to display it only 4. 
please tell me how should I do this.

The exactly  i want

```
4.33 => 4.33
4.00 => 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `floatval()` to achieve this.

e.g.

```php
var_dump(floatval(4.33));
var_dump(floatval(4.00));
```

output:

```
float 4.33

float 4
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **[floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)**.

```
echo floatval(4.00);
4

echo floatval(4.33);
4.33
```